# $or operator from mongoose not providing all necessary data when used with the find() Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the find method alongside with the $or operator to check the database for any existing duplicate data in this line

```
const duplicate = await NewItemsData.find({ $or: newItems });
```

Checking the variable in the console; `console.log(duplicate)`, I discovered that some data gotten are missing.

Here is the code - please help me out to know where this problem is coming from. The aim of the code is to create an array containing duplicate data, then filter the newItems array creating another array that contains data existing in the newItems array but not in the duplicates array.

```
const createMoneyInTransact = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 const {newItems}= req.body
 console.log(newItems)

//check the database to see if any data found in the newItems array coming in from the frontend
//already exists in the NewItemsData database if it exists, create a new array of all duplicates

  const duplicate = await NewItemsData.find({ $or: newItems });
  console.log(duplicate)
     if(Array.isArray(duplicate) && duplicate.length === 0){
        console.log('no duplicates')
         const create_newItems = await NewItemsData.create(newItems)
       console.log(create_newItems)
    }else{
        console.log('duplicate exists')
        //helper function that compares two objects in arrays by their properties
    const containsObject=(obj, arr, key)=>{
        return arr.some((element)=>{
            return element[key] === obj[key]
        })

     }

     // Filter the newItems array and keep only the objects that are 
     //not in the duplicate array
     const newUniqueItems = newItems.filter((obj)=>{
         return !containsObject(obj, duplicate, 'productName')
     })

     console.log(newUniqueItems)
     const create_newUniqueItems = await NewItemsData.create(newUniqueItems)
     console.log(create_newUniqueItems)

    }
})


//console.log Data
//console.log(newItems) displays the result below
[
  {
    productName: 'vally',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: 3619,
    quantityCount: 11,
    unitOfQuantity: 'grams',
    sellingPrice: '329'
  },
  {
    productName: 'Tridant',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: 2400,
    quantityCount: 4,
    unitOfQuantity: 'grams',
    sellingPrice: '600'
  },
  {
    productName: 'trulia',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: 1600,
    quantityCount: 4,
    unitOfQuantity: 'kg',
    sellingPrice: '400'
  },
  {
    productName: 'constr',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: 1362,
    quantityCount: 3,
    unitOfQuantity: 'kg',
    sellingPrice: '454'
  }
]
//console.log(duplicate) displays the result below
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6598d46d37efd2db72ee9ecd"),
    productName: 'Tridant',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: '2400',
    quantityCount: 4,
    unitOfQuantity: 'grams',
    sellingPrice: 600,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6599150ebd9fedd3f0b9e721"),
    productName: 'trulia',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: '1600',
    quantityCount: 4,
    unitOfQuantity: 'kg',
    sellingPrice: 400,
    __v: 0
  }
]

//productName: vally was surposed to be among the duplicate but was not picked up
//console.log(newUniqueItems) displays the result below
[
  {
    productName: 'vally',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: '3619',
    quantityCount: 11,
    unitOfQuantity: 'grams',
    sellingPrice: 329
  },
  {
    productName: 'constr',
    sellingPriceOfTotal: '1362',
    quantityCount: 3,
    unitOfQuantity: 'kg',
    sellingPrice: 454
  }
]
//but vally is not supposed to be among the filtered array because it is a duplicate hence
//the errow message below

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.newitemsdatas index: productName_1 dup key: { productName: "vally" }
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\business-books\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:50:33
    at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\business-books\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\command.js:84:64
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

//here is the NewItemsData Data Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MoneyInData = require('./MoneyInData');

const newItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    productName:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    sellingPriceOfTotal:{
      type: String,
      //required: true
    },
    quantityCount: {
        type: Number,
    },
    unitOfQuantity:{
        type: String,
    },
    costPrice:{
      type: Number,
      //required: true
    },
    sellingPrice:{
        type: Number,
       required:true
    },
    moneyInData:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MoneyInData'
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('NewItemsData', newItemsSchema);
```

Comment: this error only occurs when productName duplicate but I see your filter have many conditions. If your db have a row `productName: "vally"` but another field had different value ex `sellingPriceOfTotal: 10` in query `sellingPriceOfTotal: 3619`. You query isn't match but when you insert it only check unique  productName. You can query only one field productName in your DB to cross check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need to check `productName` matches in your query. At the minute you are checking for whole document matches, by that I mean all five of `[ productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, unitOfQuantity, sellingPrice]` need to be exact matches for the object to be a match. I suspect the document in your collection with `productName: 'vally'` has a subtle difference from the one you are using to search.

Instead, just look for matches on `productName` by trying one of these.

**Option 1 using `$or`**

```js
const {newItems} = req.body;

// Create a new array of objects containing just the productName and it's value
const newItemsNamesObj = newItems.map(o =>{
  return {productName: o.productName}
})
//Then search using $or
const duplicate = await NewItemsData.find({ 
   $or: newItemsNamesObj 
});
```

**Option 2 using `$in`**

```js
const {newItems} = req.body;

// Create a new array of String containing just the productName
const newItemsNamesStr = newItems.map(o =>{
  return o.productName
})
//Then search
const duplicate = await NewItemsData.find({
   productName: {
      $in: newItemsNamesStr
   }
});
```

Comment: Option 2 did it for me, Thank you so much, but one question, what could be the difference in the  difference in the object value Vally, what could lead such disparity when the data look the same with the query

Comment: It could be a few things for example type i.e comparing number against string in one of the properties or you could have an extra space in one of the strings or uppercase somewhere etc. Glad it worked for you @Aham_Uzoma.